# Prove that the set of all nilpotent elements are present in prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would want someone to go through my attempt instead of suggesting any another answer.

Let $x$ be an nilpotent element which is not present in the prime ideal $P$, and so $x \in a+P$ where $a$ is not zero .

Now $x^m=0$,where $m \in N$.
Now, $x^m \in (a+P)^m \in (a^m+P)$. Since $x^m=0$ so $x^m \in P$ and hence $a^m \in P$ .

Since $P$ is a prime ideal so $a.a^{m-1} \in P$ so by induction I can claim that $a \in P$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $a$ is not in $P$.

Comment: By what induction?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct, but you take the unnecessary extra step of introducing the element $a$. You could just substitute $x$ for $a$ in the last sentence of your proof.

Comment: Yeah I know I am making it more complicated. But I wanted to use the concept of quotient ring